# Android's onSignalStrengthChanged is called never during a large tcp transfer but after it multiple changes are reported

Tags: android

I'm trying to gather data on how tcp transfer speeds correlate to signal strength changes, but I can't seem to get any values from the transfer period. Callbacks are always received after the transfer is finished, sometimes even 10 values with a couple of milliseconds apart right after the transfer.

I am listening to (PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION) and these callbacks are called.

Is it possible that I am somehow blocking the OS so that it can't call the callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the TCP transfer is done using AsyncTask, the signal strengths are coming as they should. Using Java Threads was somehow blocking the events.